# The page contains too many server redirects?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect android/Iphone/Ipad users to a different web address(subdomain) but everytime it redirects on my tablet it pops up with 'The page contains too many server redirects' ?? my htaccess code on the server is as follows >

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^eco-fireplaces.co.uk/mob.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.eco-fireplaces.co.uk/mob.html[R=307,L,NC]
```

this redirects my android device to `http://m.eco-fireplaces.co.uk/mob.html%5bR=307,L,NC%5d`

but comes up with the 'The page contains too many server redirects' ?? error

Can someone help me fix this please.

Comment: BTW "too many redirects" may sometimes mean a redirect loop

Comment: Kos I am only redirecting one url ?? how can there be too many ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this redirects my android device to `http://m.eco-fireplaces.co.uk/mob.html%5bR=307,L,NC%5d`

This is because you're missing a space between `mod.html` and the rewrite flags, and the flags are being appended as if it's part of the target URL:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.eco-fireplaces.co.uk/mob.html [R=307,L,NC]
```

Not sure why this would cause a "too many server redirects" error, though.

---

The `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable does not contain path information, only the hostname specified by the "Host:" header. But in your case, it needs to read:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.eco-fireplaces.co.uk$ [NC]
```

Comment: Hi Jon thanks for getting back to me, I have altered the code to a simplified redirect to another page but i'm still getting the too many redirects error...it is definately re-directing to the page but when it gets there I get the error?? Any ideas ?  The new htaccess code is                                       RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "iphone|ipod|android" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^http://www.eco-fireplaces.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.eco-fireplaces.co.uk/mob.html [L,R=302]

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jon I have modified the .htaccess file as you said but still no luck i'm afraid....still getting the annoying 'The page contains too many server redirects' error! it's driving me nuts lol! i've been at it four 5 hours solid this morning trying to get it to work, I even spoke to a 123 reg representitive and he wasn't sure why it didn't work :/ ....have you any more solutions Jon? thanks for you time.

Comment: I've got it to work using a neat little java script...it must have been something to do with 123 Reg servers ?? not sure but this worked for me finally :) I would recommend this code for anyone who getting the same infinite redirect error using .htaccess                                                          [code]<script language=javascript>
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)))
{
location.replace("http://www.yourwebsite.com");
}
</script>[code]

Comment: I take that last comment back....the java script re-direct works but now it just keeps reloading the redirected url [Here](http://www.eco-fireplaces.co.uk/mob.html) over and over and over again!! AGHHhhhhhhh!!! what is wrong now ? i finally thought I had cracked it :( please help me get this working, I can't take the stress anymore :D

Comment: Ok let this be a lesson learned, The Java script above works fine I just forgot to remove the script from my mob.html page....DOH!! stupid me :D thats why it was constantly re-directing.